# Java regex split on whitespace /not preceded

Tags: java, regex

I would like to split  a string:`"x=   2-3   y=3 z=   this,   that"` 
I would split this up on one or more whitespaces, that are not preceded by a '=' or a ','
meaning group one: `"x=   2-3"`
              two: `"y=3"`
              three: `"z=   this,   that"`
I have an expression that kinda does it but its only good if = or , has only one whitespace after it.

```
(?<![,=])\\s+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thinking the other way around (looking forward instead of backwards), would the following do the job for you?

```
\\s+(?=\\S*=)
```

- `\\s+` - one or more whitespace characters
- `(?=\\S*=)` - positive lookahead to make sure it's followed by as many non-whitespace characters and a literal equal sign.

Comment: Thank you, perfect

Answer (score 1):

This one splits on white space followed by *some non-white space then `=`*: `"\\s+(?=[^=\\s]+=)"`:

```
jshell> "x=   2-3   y=3 z=   this,   that".split("\\s+(?=[^=\\s]+=)")
$10 ==> String[3] { "x=   2-3", "y=3", "z=   this,   that" }
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be difficult to phrase clean regex splitting logic here.  Instead, I would use a formal pattern matcher here, with the regex pattern:

```
[^=\s]+\s*=.*?(?=[^=\s]+\s*=|$)
```

Sample script:

```
String input = "x=   2-3   y=3 z=   this,   that";
String pattern = "[^=\\s]+\\s*=.*?(?=[^=\\s]+\\s*=|$)";
Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
Matcher m = r.matcher(input);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println("match: " + m.group(0));
}
```

This prints:

```
match: x=   2-3   
match: y=3 
match: z=   this,   that
```

Here is an explanation of the regex pattern:

```
[^=\s]+           match a variable
\s*               followed by optional whitespace
=                 match =
.*?               consume everything, until seeing the nearest
(?=
    [^=\s]+\s*=   the next variable followed by =
    |             or
    $             or the end of the input (covers the z= case)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the negative lookahead, you could assert what is on the left is a pattern which would match for example `x=   2-3` and match the following whitespace chars.

Use a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) `[^\\h=,]` to match any char except what it listed.

```
(?<=[^\\h=,]=\\h{0,100}[^\\h=,]{1,100})\\h+
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VxUpc9/1) | [Java demo](https://ideone.com/jAvFB6)

The regex demo has a different engine selected only to show the matches.

In Java you have to use double escapes and you could use `\h` to match 1+ horizontal whitespace chars in stead of `\s`

Java does not support infinite width in a lookbehind, but does support a finite width.

For example

```
String s = "x=   2-3   y=3 z=   this,   that";
String regex = "(?<=[^\\h=,]=\\h{0,100}[^\\h=,]{1,100})\\h+";
String parts[] = s.split(regex);

for (String part : parts)
    System.out.println(part);
```

Output

```
x=   2-3
y=3
z=   this,   that
```